# Electron/JS Wait till varible gets data from a different function

Tags: javascript, arrays, electron

I am currently learning to use Electron for a university project. What I am trying to do is to read data from a .xlsx file, then create a Chart with chart.js and display the data. For that, I am using exceljs and chart.js. For this, I wrote multiple functions (Code below). My problem right now is, that I try to return an Array with some data (It gets created perfectly fine) but it just displays as `undefined` in the other function.

I know, my code is not good. It's complete spaghetti, honestly. I just need to get this working, it doesn't have to be nice code.

This is the function I use to draw the chart:

```
function createGraph() {
    // Create Canvas if not already created
    if (document.getElementById('datacanvas') == null) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "datacanvas")
        var datadiv = document.getElementById("datadiv");
        datadiv.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
    else {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('datacanvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }

    var labls = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni",
        "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
    var datasts = createDatasets();
    console.log(datasts);

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labls,
            datasets: datasts
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The problem I have is the varible `datasts` or rather, the `data` property because the data is undefined. It gets created with these two functions:

```
function createDatasets() {
    console.log("createDatasets");
    var dataset = [];

    var rdbStrom = document.getElementById('rdbStrom');
    var rdbGas = document.getElementById('rdbGas');
    var rdbWasser = document.getElementById('rdbWasser');
    var rdbGesamt = document.getElementById('rdbGesamt');

    if (rdbStrom.checked) {
        var set = {
            label: 'Stromkosten',
            data: getDataArray("strom"),
            borderColor: '#FF0000',
            borderWidth: 1
        };
        dataset.push(set);
    }

    if (rdbGas.checked) {
        var set = {
            label: 'Gaskosten',
            data: getDataArray("gas"),
            borderColor: '#00FF00',
            borderWidth: 1
        };
        dataset.push(set);
    }

    if (rdbWasser.checked) {
        var set = {
            label: 'Wasserkosten',
            data: getDataArray("wasser"),
            borderColor: '#0000FF',
            borderWidth: 1
        };
        dataset.push(set);
    }

    if (rdbGesamt.checked) {
        ;
        var set = {
            label: 'Gesamtkosten',
            data: getDataArray("gesamt"),
            borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        };
        dataset.push(set);
    }

    // Wait
    setTimeout(() => {
        return dataset;
    }, 1000);

}

function getDataArray(type) {
    console.log("getDataArray");

    var data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var period = [];
    var start = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
    var end = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);
    var tmp = new Date(start);

    do {
        period.push(tmp.toDateString());

        tmp.setDate(tmp.getDate() + 1);
    } while (tmp <= end)

    if (!fs.existsSync('./Data.xlsx')) {
        alert("Error finding File 'Data.xlsx'.");
    }
    else {
        switch (type) {
            case "strom": {
                workbook.xlsx.readFile('./Data.xlsx')
                    .then(function () {
                        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Data');

                        for (var i = 2; i <= worksheet.rowCount; i++) {
                            var r = worksheet.getRow(i);
                            var d = new Date(r.getCell(1).value);

                            if (period.includes(d.toDateString())) {
                                var vbr = r.getCell(3).value;
                                var prc = r.getCell(4).value;
                                var gprc = r.getCell(5).value;
                                var tax = r.getCell(6).value;
                                var kosten = (vbr * prc) + gprc + tax;
                                data[d.getMonth()] = data[d.getMonth()] + kosten;

                            }
                        }
                    })

                break;
            }
            case "gas": {
                workbook.xlsx.readFile('./Data.xlsx')
                    .then(function () {
                        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Data');

                        for (var i = 2; i <= worksheet.rowCount; i++) {
                            var r = worksheet.getRow(i);
                            var date = new Date(r.getCell(1).value);

                            if (period.includes(date.toDateString())) {
                                var vbr = r.getCell(8).value;
                                var prc = r.getCell(9).value;
                                var gprc = r.getCell(10).value;
                                var tax = r.getCell(11).value;
                                var kosten = (vbr * prc) + gprc + tax;
                                data[d.getMonth()] = data[d.getMonth()] + kosten;

                            }
                        }
                    })
                break;
            }
            case "wasser": {
                workbook.xlsx.readFile('./Data.xlsx')
                    .then(function () {
                        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Data');

                        for (var i = 2; i <= worksheet.rowCount; i++) {
                            var r = worksheet.getRow(i);
                            var date = new Date(r.getCell(1).value);

                            if (period.includes(date.toDateString())) {
                                var vbr = r.getCell(13).value;
                                var prc = r.getCell(14).value;
                                var gprc = r.getCell(15).value;
                                var tax = r.getCell(16).value;
                                var kosten = (vbr * prc) + gprc + tax;
                                data[d.getMonth()] = data[d.getMonth()] + kosten;

                            }
                        }
                    })
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Wait till process is done reading file
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Timeout")
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log("Data[" + i + " ]: " + data[i]);
        }
        console.log("Return DataArray");
        return data;
    }, 1000);

}
```

Again, I know my code is not good, I just need to get this working.
The output in the console is the following:

```
createDataset
getDataArray
undefined // This is the datasts Variable which I need to wait for
Timeout // This comes from the third function
// Here it displays the data it read from the Excel file from the third function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of asynchronicity issue, you use createDatasets as if it was a synchronous function (such as return 1 + 2) while it relies on asynchronous operations,
ie :

```
let exampleInt = 0
setTimeout(() => {

        // callback
        exampleInt = 1;
        return dataset;
    }, 1000);

// This will be reached before the callback executes, so exampleInt equals 0
```

You should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises to achieve your goal which is, I guess, wait the end of an operation before executing code based on the result of that operation

Does it brighten your mind ?

---

Now resolution, first function : **createDatasets**

```
function createDatasets() {
    console.log("createDatasets");
    var dataset = [];

    var rdbStrom = document.getElementById('rdbStrom');
    var rdbGas = document.getElementById('rdbGas');
    var rdbWasser = document.getElementById('rdbWasser');
    var rdbGesamt = document.getElementById('rdbGesamt');

    // storing each label we need
    let dataArraysNeeded = [];
    let dataArraysNeededAsPromises = [];

    let designParams = {
        "strom": {
            title: "Stromkosten",
            color: "#FF0000"
        },
        "gas": {
            title: "Gaskosten",
            color: "#00FF00"
        },
        "wasser": {
            title: "Wasserkosten",
            color: "#0000FF"
        },
        "gesamt": {
            title: "Gesamtkosten",
            color: "#FFFFFF"
        }
    };

    if (rdbStrom.checked) {

        dataArraysNeeded.push('strom');

    }

    if (rdbGas.checked) {

        dataArraysNeeded.push('gas');
    }

    if (rdbWasser.checked) {

        dataArraysNeeded.push('wasser');
    }

    if (rdbGesamt.checked) {

        dataArraysNeeded.push('gesamt');

    }

    // From here we have an array of labels (ex: ["wasser","gesamt"])
    // We now want to get the data array for each of these labels, here is how it's done

    for (let i = 0; i < dataArraysNeeded.length; i++) {
        dataArraysNeededAsPromises.push(getDataArray(dataArraysNeeded[i]));
    }

    // This will execute all the promises AND WAIT the end of the slowest promise
    return Promise.all(dataArraysNeededAsPromises).then((sets) => {

        let currentLabel = "";

        // sets[0] equals getDataArray("wasser") for example
        for (let j = 0; j < sets.length; j++) {

            currentLabel = dataArrayLabel[j]; // "wasser"

            dataset.push( {

                label: designParams[currentLabel]["title"],
                data: sets[j],
                borderColor: designParams[currentLabel]["color"],
                borderWidth: 1

            });

        }

        return dataset; // Array of objects {label, data, borderColor, borderWidth}

    });

}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all for details on how works Promise.all

---

Your main function **createGraph** which calls createDatasets (you can see how the result of a function returning a promise is consumed)

```
function createGraph() {
    // Create Canvas if not already created
    if (document.getElementById('datacanvas') == null) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute("id", "datacanvas")
        var datadiv = document.getElementById("datadiv");
        datadiv.appendChild(canvas);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
    else {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('datacanvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }

    var labls = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni",
        "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];


    // Here you instanciate your promise of Dataset, which IS NOT synchronous
    var datasetPromise = createDatasets();

    // So you need to specifiy a callback, executed on promise completion
    return datasetPromise.then((yourDatasetReadyToBeUsed) => {

        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labls,
                datasets: yourDatasetReadyToBeUsed
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        return 'completed !';
    });

}
```

I'll let you find the last one as it's very similar to those two functions (getDataArray needs to return a Promise too as it reads a file) !
Is it more clear for you ?

Comment: Hey, so I just tested around a bit and it's working, thanks! However, the way you wrote createDatasets() it only ever allows for one set of data. Is there a way to store the datasets in an array and return that array to the main function to complete the Promise, so that it would draw multiple lines in the chart?

Comment: Oh sure, I will edit my answer just give me some time !

Comment: I've changed createDatasets to allow multiple sets, could you mark topic as solved if it's the case ? Thanks @DominikAlbert :)